# Best pattern to link angular ui-router and ngResouce

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngresource

I've made a state linked for my contacts.

```
 state('contactsdetail',{ // single contact    
   url: '/contact/:contactId',                 
   templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',        
   controller: 'contactCtrl'                   
 }).
```

What is the cleanest pattern to link ui-router and ngResource so that a state loads a resource as my state changes contact Id?

(ideally I'll cache my contact Id to check if the required contact is already loaded before asking for a new one - but this is not essential)

Answer (score 0):

So a better google yielded these two resources, which I will post as an answer, as strictly they do answer my questions.

**But** I am still hoping for something that feels a bit neater (and perhaps someone may choose to post a more tightly packaged pattern)

- [a complex resolve-based approach](http://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/)
- [a simple approach](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/])